# generic command line generator in python

Tags: python, argparse

Is there a generic command line generator in python? I mean something that is like argparse but has the opposite functionality. argparse lets you define various arguments and then parses a given command line string into values of those arguments. I need something that lets you define various arguments like argparse, but given a dict of argument, value pairs will generate a command line string.

Example :

```
    gencmdline = CmdlineGenerator()
    gencmdline.add_argument('-f', '--foo')
    gencmdline.add_argument('bar')
    gencmdline.add_argument('phi')
    gencmdline.gen_cmdline(phi='hello', bar=1, foo=2) returns: 
    "1 hello -f 2"
    gencmdline.gen_cmdline(phi='hello', bar=1) returns:
    "1 hello"
    gencmdline.gen_cmdline(phi='hello', foo=2) raise exception because positional argument bar is not specified.
```

Comment: What you're asking is much simpler than the functionality of argparse; you should be able to implement it yourself without too much difficulty. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Examples would be helpful.

Comment: You have the solution there, do you not?  Create your dictionary and join all the key/value pairs into a string.  What's the problem?

Comment: Yes, it is much simpler than argparse and probably not to difficult to make my own. Just want to check if there is something around already which I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There probably is enough information in the `Actions` generated by a regular `parser` definition to do this job.

To take part of your example:

```
In [122]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [123]: arglist = []
In [124]: arg1 = parser.add_argument('-f','--foo')    
In [126]: arglist.append(arg1)
In [128]: arg2=parser.add_argument('bar')
In [129]: arglist.append(arg2)
In [131]: arg3=parser.add_argument('phi')
In [132]: arglist.append(arg3)

In [133]: arglist
Out[133]: 
[_StoreAction(option_strings=['-f', '--foo'], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None),

 _StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='bar', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None),

 _StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='phi', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)]
```

`add_argument` creates an `Action` object (subclass actually based on `action` type), with attributes that are either defaults or ones you specify with parameters.

In this example I am collecting them both as variables, `arg1` and elements of a list.  There are other attributes that aren't shown in this `repr`.  You can explore those in an interactive interpreter.

From your dictionary, `dict(phi='hello', bar=1, foo=2)` and this list you can deduce that the argument with `dest='foo'` has an option string (`-f` or `--foo`), and everything else is default (`nargs=None` is the default 1 argument).  `dest='bar'` is postional with an empty `option_strings`.  You'll have to be careful and note that `bar` occurs before `phi`.

```
parser._actions
```

is the same list of Actions, with the addition of `-h`.

Comment: That can be quite useful. I will explore this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to use something like `call` and pass a command some set of keywords.

```
from subprocess import call

def get_call_array(command=command,**kwargs):
    callarray = [command]
    for k, v in self.kwargs.items():
        callarray.append("--" + k)
        if v:
            callarray.append(str(v))
    return callarray

call(get_call_array("my_prog",height=5,width=10,trials=100,verbose=None))

#calls:   my_prog --height 5 --width 10 --trials 100  --verbose
```

Of course, if you have a dictionary, of all your parameters, it's even easier:

```
def get_call_array_from_dict(command,options_dict):
    callarray=[command]
    for k,v in options_dict.items():
        callarray.append("--" + str(k))
        if v:
            callarray.append(str(v))
    return callarray
```